# Encoder weights are not initialized when loading pre trained model

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm writing a custom class on top of `XLMRobertaModel`, but when initializing the model from a pre-trained checkpoint, I get a warning saying the `encoder.layer.*` weights were not initialized from the respective checkpoint.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the error:

```py
from transformers import XLMRobertaModel

class CustomXLM(XLMRobertaModel):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)

        self.roberta = XLMRobertaModel(config)

        self.init_weights()

custom_xlm = CustomXLM.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-base", num_labels=2)
```

Upon running this I get (check the 4th line):

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at xlm-roberta-base were not used when initializing CustomXLM: ['lm_head.dense.weight', 'lm_head.layer_norm.weight', 'lm_head.dense.bias', 'lm_head.bias', 'lm_head.decoder.weight', 'lm_head.layer_norm.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing CustomXLM from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing CustomXLM from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Some weights of CustomXLM were not initialized from the model checkpoint at xlm-roberta-base and are newly initialized: ['encoder.layer.6.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.0.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.2.output.dense.bias', 'embeddings.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.5.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.self.value.bias', 'embeddings.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.1.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.3.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.2.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.7.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.9.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.10.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.7.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.3.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.self.value.weight', 'pooler.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.5.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.7.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.3.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.3.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.6.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.1.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.8.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'embeddings.position_embeddings.weight', 'encoder.layer.5.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.5.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.1.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.7.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.10.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.4.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'embeddings.token_type_embeddings.weight', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.2.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.10.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.4.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.4.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.10.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.2.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.11.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.10.output.dense.weight', 'embeddings.word_embeddings.weight', 'encoder.layer.10.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.2.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.9.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.3.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.2.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.4.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.6.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.6.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.1.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.8.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.self.value.bias', 'encoder.layer.3.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.11.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.5.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.9.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.7.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.0.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.3.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.attention.self.query.weight', 'encoder.layer.4.intermediate.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.8.output.LayerNorm.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.attention.self.value.weight', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.5.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.2.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.5.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.4.output.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.4.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.6.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.7.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.6.attention.self.query.bias', 'pooler.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.self.query.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.attention.self.key.weight', 'encoder.layer.11.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight', 'encoder.layer.6.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.0.intermediate.dense.weight', 'encoder.layer.10.attention.self.key.bias', 'encoder.layer.9.output.dense.bias', 'encoder.layer.7.attention.self.key.weight']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```

I understand some of the weights are supposed to be newly initialized. Specifically the ones related to `lm_head`. But I don't understand why the encoder weights are not loaded correctly.

I have a working example using BERT, primarily based from this [code](https://github.com/semantic-web-company/wic-tsv/blob/master/HyperBert/HyperBert3.py). It inherits from `BertPreTrainedModel` and has `self.bert = BertModel(config)` in the `__init__` function. This class also overrides the `forward` function.

With that, I tried inheriting from `RobertaPreTrainedModel` and keeping the line `self.roberta = XLMRobertaModel(config)`. And although all warnings go away, I get a message saying:

```
You are using a model of type xlm-roberta to instantiate a model of type roberta. This is not supported for all configurations of models and can yield errors.
```

That said, my questions are:

1. What is the correct way of creating a custom model?
2. Should I have `self.roberta = XLMRobertaModel(config)` in the `__init__` if I want to use a pretrained model? As far as I understood [the docs](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter2/3?fw=pt), calling `XLMRobertaModel(config)` will return me a newly initialized model.

**Edit:**
Related to question 2. I saw that transformers does some magic depending on the name of the attribute you have your model on. [This link](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8407) has some more details.

Comment: Which version of transformers are you using? Also, does loading the pre-trained model without a custom class (i.e., `model = XLMRobertaModel.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-base")` work, or also fail with the same error? For version 4.18, I cannot reproduce the problem when loading the pre-trained model.

Comment: Hi @dennlinger, I have version 4.15 and by running without a custom class, I get no error. Do you mean that you could not reproduce the error by using the code snippet I provided or by running without a custom class?

Answer (score -1):

Since I dont have the code and pretrianed model, I can only tell you how to load the model accurately.

Before you load load the model weights, I suggest you first print the model parameter names you define by

```py
model = XXXNet()

for names, params in model.named_parameters():
    print(names)
```

Then check thei weights names of your pretrained model weights by

```py
state_dict = torch.load('path/to/wegiths')

for keys, values in state_dict.items():
    print(keys)
```

You shoudl carefully check whether the names of two operations match or not.

Comment: The checkpoint I'm using is in my first code snippet, which should be enough to reproduce the error!